# why Plot Python 3 different with Matlab and even excel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Im trying to read Data from scv file and plot them.Reading process easily worked but by Plotting is full missed up.
I have tried that with MATLAB and even Excel. Both are plotting correct but in python 3 i have problems.it seems like that.
[Plot Photo with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByWfW.png)
[Plot Photo with MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcmOv.png)

I would be thankful for your help

```
filename1=fd.askopenfilename(title='open expander text data to graphic ')
reader=csv.reader(filename1)
xpoints = []
ypoints = []
for line in reader:
    xpoints.append(line[0])
    ypoints.append(line[1])
xpoints_to_graph=np.array(xpoints[])
ypoints_to_graph=np.array(ypoints[])

plt.plot(xpoints_to_graph,ypoints_to_graph)
```

Comment: `csv.reader` returns objects (`line[0], line[1]`) as strings. You need to convert to their correct datatype, e.g `ypoints.append(float(line[1]))`. Also consider `import pandas as pd; df=pd.read_csv(filename1)`

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve]. There are a lot of broken bits in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `line` is a tuple of *strings*. Thus, `xpoints` and `ypoints` are lists of *strings*. Matplotlib will thus attempt to put *all* possible values as ticks, which is why the plot is so cluttered.

You should treat each element of `line` as a number:

```
xpoints = []
ypoints = []
for line in reader:
    xpoints.append(float(line[0]))
    ypoints.append(float(line[1]))
```

Alternatively, use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt), which will automatically convert numbers to floating-point or integer types.